# Good and scalable method to create network client and make network call in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a large project which requires lot of network calls. Right now I have created a WebApiClass and here I have written my entire app network calls. But I don't think this is the right way.

**Sample Code**

```
class WebApiCall{

Dio _dio = Dio();

  Dio get dio {
    _dio.options.baseUrl = BASE_URL;
    _dio.options.headers = {'token': '$tokenKey'};
    return _dio;
  }

//I have written more than 100 networks calls like this in this class
  Future<List<CompletedSessionData>?> getSessionData(int id) async{
    List<CompletedSessionData>? completedSessionsData;
    try{
      final response = await dio.post('path', data: {'id': id});
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        //Codes for decoding
      }
    } catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
    return completedSessionsData;
  }

}
```

*I create a dependency injection with provider of this class to use it everywhere in my app*

I want to refactor my code and instead of writing all my network call in one class I want to divide in multiple class but I don't want to create multiple Dio client and provide my base URL and toke multiple times.

Please suggest me some good and scalable method for solving my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this some time ago which basically is a service for all types of calls needed using generic types:

```
class APIService {
  APIService(this.baseUrl, this.token) {
    _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: baseUrl));
    _dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";
  }

  final String token;
  final String baseUrl;
  var _dio;

  Future<T> get<T>(
      {required String path,
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json)? builder,
      Map<String, dynamic>? query}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.get(path, queryParameters: query);
      return builder != null ? builder(response.data) : response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
        throw SocketException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        throw TimeoutException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        throw HttpException(e.response != null ? e.response!.data.toString() : e.message);
      } else {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<T> getValue<T>(
      {required String path,
      T Function(dynamic data)? builder,
      Map<String, dynamic>? query}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.get(path, queryParameters: query);
      return builder != null ? builder(response.data) : response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
        throw SocketException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        throw TimeoutException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        throw HttpException(e.response != null ? e.response!.data.toString() : e.message);
      } else {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<List<T>> getAll<T>(
      {required String path,
      required List<T> Function(List<dynamic> json) builder,
      Map<String, dynamic>? query}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.get(path, queryParameters: query);
      return builder(response.data);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
        throw SocketException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        throw TimeoutException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        throw HttpException(e.response != null ? e.response!.data.toString() : e.message);
      } else {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<T> post<T, I>(
      {required String path,
      I? data,
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json)? builder}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.post(path, data: data);
      return builder != null ? builder(response.data) : response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
        throw SocketException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        throw TimeoutException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        throw HttpException(e.response != null ? e.response!.data.toString() : e.message);
      } else {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<T> patch<T, I>(
      {required String path,
      I? data,
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json)? builder}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.patch(path, data: data);
      return builder != null ? builder(response.data) : response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
        throw SocketException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        throw TimeoutException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        throw HttpException(e.response != null ? e.response!.data.toString() : e.message);
      } else {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }

  Future<T> delete<T, I>(
      {required String path,
      I? data,
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json)? builder}) async {
    try {
      final response = await _dio.delete(path, data: data);
      return builder != null ? builder(response.data) : response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
      if (e.type == DioErrorType.other) {
        throw SocketException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.connectTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.receiveTimeout ||
          e.type == DioErrorType.sendTimeout) {
        throw TimeoutException(e.message);
      } else if (e.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        throw HttpException(e.response != null ? e.response!.data.toString() : e.message);
      } else {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I would use it like this inside my repo implementation:

```
  @override
  Future<List<Ticket>>? getTickets({int? offset, int? state, String? query}) {
    return _service.getAll(
        path: APIPath.tickets(offset: offset, state: state, query: query),
        builder: Ticket.ticketsFromJson);
  }

  @override
  Future<Ticket>? getTicket(String id) {
    return _service.get(
        path: APIPath.ticket(id), builder: (data) => Ticket.fromJson(data));
  }
```

Comment: Can I create a singleton of this class?

Comment: Sure, I'm using a singleton in the usage example `_service`.

Comment: I don't think APIService class is  declared as signleton.